# Saving Magento configuration doesn't change the actual value

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, configuration, system-configuration

In Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Contact.

I am changing the email template and clicking the Save button, The page gets reloaded and says **You saved the configuration** but the email template in the dropdown field is not really changed. Also, I couldn't reproduce this issue in my Local setup but the issue is present on the Live site. (**Especially in-store views**)

Have tried the following, unfortunately, none of them worked.

1. Cleared Cache
2. Indexer reindex
3. There are no configurations saved in the config.php for additional configurations

Comment: select store from top left dropdown and than try to save

Comment: Yes, I have changed the scope and saved it, yet the values are not changing.

Comment: The below solution helped me to fix this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24562533/12709032

Answer (score 1):

Please run the all following command in Magento root directory...

```
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
-> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
-> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
-> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
-> php bin/magento cache:flush
-> php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and then also check the value in **core_config_data** database table

Answer (score 0):

I have earlier face this issue and it got working after clearing cache & deploy the content.

Please clear all cache and if there are any server cache then clear that also.